# When I use regular expression many times in every frame, FPS fell

Tags: c++, regex

I'm creating a game.

I wrote a code which is checking whether character string match with else specified character string using regular expression in every frame.

```
void function update()
{
    string data[] = {"root", "body_bone", "body", "arm_left", "arm_right", "arm_right_sword", "body_belt", "face", "hair", "leg_left", "leg_right"};
    vector<string> arrayA(data, end(data));

    string data2[] = {"03golden/golden_arm_right_sword", "03golden/golden_arm_right", "03golden/golden_leg_left", "03golden/golden_leg_right", "03golden/golden_body", "03golden/golden_belt", "03golden/golden_arm_left", "face_04", "face_03", "face_02", "face_01", "03golden/golden_hair"};
    vector<string> arrayB(data2, end(data2));

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayB.size(); j++)
        {
            string s1 = arrayA[i];
            string s2 = arrayB[j];

            cmatch results;
            stringstream ss;
            ss << s1 << "$";
            regex pattern(ss.str());

            if (regex_search(s2.c_str(), results, pattern))
            {
                // something process
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I check whether each character string in array 'arrayA' match with suffix of each character string in array 'arrayB'.

But above process make FPS fell to one fifth.

It seems that when I check long character string in regular expression many times, FPS fell.

How should I use regular expression?

Comment: Regular expressions are powerful but also overly complex and *expensive* in terms of performance. Especially if, like you do, they are recompiled multiple times in a nested loop. My guess is that you don't really need regular expressions at all, it seems like you could just use e.g. [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Comment: On an unrelated note, you don't need your temporary arrays, you could just as easily do `static const vector<string> arrayA = { "root", "body_bone", ... };`

Comment: I think memory allocations are hurting you more than the regular expressions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Regex is not necessarily expensive. If you have a language that allows possessives and/or atomic groups, a regex can basically be as efficient as a parser function. That being said, it's not always the best tool for the job, especially when a simple `find` would suffice.

Comment: Things will be much faster if you move `string s1 = arrayA[i];` and the construction of the regular expression outside of the inner loop. Those two depend only on the value of `i`, so don't have to be recalculated for every value of `j`. But things will be even faster if you don't use a regular expression for a simple string search.

Comment: @Graham -- since this is a question about C++, the performance of regular expressions in other languages isn't particularly relevant. That said, with almost no exceptions, the answer to questions I've seen about regular expressions on this forum is "don't do it".

Comment: @PeteBecker That's true, the C++ regex standard libraries aren't very robust compared to PCRE (for example). But then I guess it comes down to a question of what's worthwhile to for standard library authors to implement, especially when adding more power is more potential code obfuscation. Most of the questions I've seen are duplicates due to some misunderstanding of regex, or ask about things regex is not well-suited for (e.g. HTML parsing). However, for string operations like swapping substrings, regex can be the most elegant solution. Regex *is* high-expertise, but I find it very useful.

Comment: Thank you everyone.
I tried to move string s1 = arrayA[i]; and the construction of the regular expression outside of the inner loop, but it seemed that FPS didn't improve.
It seemed that regular expression impacted on performance than something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should I use regular expression?

You probably don't want to use regex at all for this, simple string `rfind` would already be faster, and even that could be improved, but without knowing anything about how you run it it is difficult to say. Try something like this and see if it improved FPS:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void update()
{
    std::vector<std::string> arrayA = { "root", "body_bone", "body", "arm_left", "arm_right", "arm_right_sword", "body_belt", "face", "hair", "leg_left", "leg_right" };
    std::vector<std::string> arrayB = { "03golden/golden_arm_right_sword", "03golden/golden_arm_right", "03golden/golden_leg_left", "03golden/golden_leg_right", "03golden/golden_body", "03golden/golden_belt", "03golden/golden_arm_left", "face_04", "face_03", "face_02", "face_01", "03golden/golden_hair" };
    size_t pos;

    for (auto const &s1 : arrayA)
        for (auto const &s2 : arrayB)
            if ((pos = s2.rfind(s1)) != std::string::npos && pos == s2.size() - s1.size())
                 std::cout << s1 << " => " << s2 << "\n";
}

int main() 
{
    update();
}
```

https://ideone.com/OG65qT

```
body => 03golden/golden_body
arm_left => 03golden/golden_arm_left
arm_right => 03golden/golden_arm_right
arm_right_sword => 03golden/golden_arm_right_sword
hair => 03golden/golden_hair
leg_left => 03golden/golden_leg_left
leg_right => 03golden/golden_leg_right
```

Comment: As you thought, performance got faster when I used rfind.
I understand that regular expression is expensive, so I'd like to be careful about how to handle regular expression.
Thank you for your advice